# Invalid-grant when trying to get access_token with google auth_code in asp web api and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin, google-signin

I'm developing google sign in SSO services for our mobile app clients. our services are on dotNet platform (ASP.Net web Api) and our authentication handler is ASP Identity along with OWIN as it's middle-ware. our clients use native google libraries to communicate through google (for authentication) and 
finally when user is authenticated with google, google returns two important values in it's call back event, those values are **"id_token"** and **"auth_code"**

as I read earlier (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access), **auth_code** should be **exchanged** with **access_token** and **access_token** should be **given** **to the client** in order to have access to authorized resources.

when I want to exchange auth_code (sent by client) with access_token I call OWIN token endpoint with the following request parameters

- grant_type (authorization_code)
- code
- client_id
- client_secret
  note that since my clients are mobile apps I don't send redirect_uri parameter

**my response is always "invalid_grant"** but when I send the exact same request (with the same data) to google token endpoint, it (google token endpoint) easily gives me access_token with (some extra data such as expiry), so my parameters of request are correct but I have no idea why I can't get access_token from my own local service

here is sample of my request body:
grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTH_CODE&client_id=MYCLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET

I also set my localhost web api url for both "Authorized JavaScript origins" and "Authorized redirect URIs" fields in google console but didn't work

I think I've missed some thing (maybe in my configurations).
It might be possibly because my api codes are not deployed on a public domain, if so why google sso process still works fine with localhost for web clients (even though I specified localhost in google console)

do note that I have this problem only for mobile app clients, for web clients, integration of google oauth,asp Identity and OWIN works like magic because in google call back to specified redirect_uri , google appends access_token as query string parameter (no need to pass auth_code to api server to get access_token).

here is my GoogleOauth Configurations in startup.cs file

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "MYCLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "MYCLIENTSECRET"


        });
```

I've been pulling my hair over this issue, any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? i am having the same issues an help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the way to address the issue but I found another way to overcome this problem, I mean sign in by google from web Api (for mobile apps).

client SDKs (Android, IOS etc) for google SSO has an identical mechanism, when the user signs into google successfully and return to app Google SDK returns an one time used token to client called **`Auth Code`** , if you send this code to google OAuth2 api end point (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) with the following format `$"grant_type=authorization_code&code={YOUR AUTH CODE}&client_id={YOUR CLIENT ID (set in google dev console)}&client_secret={YOUR CLIENT SECRET (set in google dev console)}"` you receive an access token by which you can access google services (google drive, gmail etc).

so you can call that api directly (with HttpClient) and if you receive that access_token it indicates that the user has successfully logged in to google so you can check if they have account in your local DB, log them in by calling ***your*** local token endpoint otherwise  register the user (with a default password) and then call your token endpoint (I know it's a bit dirty to call your api endpoint within your api application but you know in my case and since nobody answered this question I had no choice).

here are my codes

in my account controller

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoginWithGoogle(string email, string ac)
    {
        var appType = StoreContext.GetApplicationType();
        var requestStoreFrontType = Request.Headers["StoreFrontType"];
        #region removing mobile header (for google)
        //if not removing, google Api will reject our request
        Request.RemoveHeaderIfExist("StoreFrontType");
        Request.RemoveHeaderIfExist("StoreFrontVersion");
        Request.RemoveHeaderIfExist("Client_Token");
        Request.RemoveHeaderIfExist("Content-Type");
        #endregion

        var _googleService = new GoogleExternalLoginService();
        var registerResult = _googleService.LoginExternal(ac, appType);
        if (registerResult.Status == ServiceResultStatus.Success)
        {
            var pass = defaultPass;
            var registermodel = new RegisterViewModel();
            registermodel.AcceptPolicy = true;
            registermodel.Email = email;
            registermodel.EnableNewsLetter = true;
            registermodel.Password = pass;
            string getTokenUrl = "";
        var existedUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(registermodel.Email);
            if (existedUser == null)
            {
                var owinUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email, RegistrationType = GetUserRegTypeByExternalProviderName("Google") };

                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(owinUser, registermodel.Password);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                        return new DSJson(null, registerResult.Message, registerResult.Status);

                getTokenUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority 
                    +"/Token";
            }
            else
            {
                ECS.Cache.CacheFacade.Store(ac, email, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2));
                getTokenUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority
                              + "/Token" + $"?IsSSO=1&AuthCode={ac}";

            }

            var getTokenParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
            getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", registermodel.Email));
            getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", registermodel.Password));
            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //headers.Add("StoreFrontType", StoreContext.StoreFrontType);
            //headers.Add("StoreFrontVersion", StoreContext.StoreFrontVersion);
            //headers.Add("Client_Token", StoreContext.ClientToken);
            var tokenResponse = HttpHelper.CallService<object>(getTokenUrl, "Post", null, getTokenParams.ToArray(), headers).Data;
            return new DSJson(tokenResponse, isResultDataInServiceResult: true);
        }
        return new DSJson(null, "operation failed, auth_code is invalid", ServiceResultStatus.Fail);
    }
```

note that I had to remove all my clients custom headers before sending request to google endpoint because google rejects your request if there is any extra custom header in your request.

here is LoginExternal method code that I used inside the action

```
 public ServiceResult<ExternalTokenView> LoginExternal(string requestCode,ApplicationType appType)
    {

        var res = new ServiceResult<ExternalTokenView>();
        var getTokenParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", requestCode));
        getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientIds[appType.ToString()]));
        if (appType == ApplicationType.AppAndroid)
            getTokenParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecrets[appType.ToString()]));
        var getTokenUrl = TokenEndpoint;
        var response = HttpHelper.CallService<ExternalTokenView>(getTokenUrl, "Post", null, rowData: getTokenParams.ToArray());
        res.Data = response.Data;
        res.Status = response.Status;
        return res;

    }
```

Note that for IOS client you shouldn't send client secret (it should be sent only for android clients).

And finally here is my token endpoint codes

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            // برای کاربرانی که قبلا اکانت داشته اند که پسوردشان متفاوت با پسورد پیش فرض برای 
            //external logins
            //است
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request["IsSSO"]))
            {
                var authCode = HttpContext.Current.Request["AuthCode"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
                {
                    var emailInCache = ECS.Cache.CacheFacade.Get<string>(authCode);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailInCache))
                    {
                        user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(emailInCache);
                        Cache.CacheFacade.Remove(authCode);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "ایمیل/موبایل یا رمز عبور نا معتبر است");
                return;
            }
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        properties.Dictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserRegisterationType",((byte)user.RegistrationType).ToString()));
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);

    }
```

you might have noticed that I stored authcode value in cahce inside my `LoginWithGoogle` action and read the value from cache in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method in order to be able to grant user token when we don't have their password (for those who had already a gmail account). but the reason of reading auth code from cache is that the exceptioned process can be used only for those whose came from google and other users must pass through normal process (getting token with their username and password)

hope it helps

Comment: @petar.kekez here is the answer